# Workaround for exporting data to Excel with more than 255 columns

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools

**SSMS** and **SSRS** to Excel enable for more than 255 columns when copy-pasting.

**SSIS** does not allow for more than 255 columns to be exported to Excel 2007. 
Is there a way to override this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem

There are a lot of Limitations when [exporting to an Excel Files using Sql server data tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255234(v=sql.110).aspx)

## Workarounds

You can do some workaround to achieve this:

1. Create a dataflowtask that export your data into a `FlatFile` (*csv*)
2. Store your Destination FileName in a Variable
3. Create another Dataflowtask that convert your csv file to an Excel File using a script task with a similar Function

*Note: you have to add `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll` file to the following directories (.Net Framework dll directory)  `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727` and (sql server data tools dll directory) `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn` (using vs 2005 and sql 2008) and then add this dll as a reference in your script task*

```
    Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

    Public Sub ConvertCSVToExcel(Fromcsv As String, Toxlsx As String)
        Dim Exl As New Excel.Application()
        Try
            Dim wb1 As Excel.Workbook = Exl.Workbooks.Open(Fromcsv, Format:=4)
            wb1.SaveAs(Toxlsx, FileFormat:=XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook)
            wb1.Close()
            Exl.Quit()
        Catch ex As Exception

                        Exl.DisplayAlerts = False
            Exl.Quit()

        End Try
    End Sub
```

### Third party components

Or you have to use a third party components like [cozyRoc SSIS+](http://www.cozyroc.com/)

### Side Note

if you are looking to Import data from excel with more than 255 columns you can follow this [Link](https://waheedrous.wordpress.com/2014/01/14/ssis-importing-an-excel-file-with-over-255-columns/)

---

## References

*Third party components*

- [SSIS: Export more than 255 columns from SQL table to Exce](http://cbtr.net/red8rain/2012/04/17/ssis-export-more-than-255-columns-from-sql-table-to-excel/)
- [Cozyroc website](http://www.cozyroc.com/)

*Workaround*

- [convert csv to xlsx](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/74df1378-7c0c-4c0f-b174-fa97a5c2969b/convert-csv-to-xlsx?forum=Vsexpressvb)
- [trying to use custom assembly with script task in SSIS 2008 - can't find correct version of GACUtil](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e8fe9b48-d299-4dd2-95f7-bfc46825cf6d/trying-to-use-custom-assembly-with-script-task-in-ssis-2008-cant-find-correct-version-of-gacutil?forum=sqlintegrationservices)

Answer (score 1):

Refer the [link](http://www.jmp.com/support/notes/33/421.html). Best would be to create an script in SSIS to copy the content as csv format. You can use c# or VB.Net.

Answer (score 1):

just for anyone come to this page and use  **SQL Server Import and Export Wizard** to export to excel

in tab **Review Data Type Mapping**
section Data Type Mapping:  ==> double click your column that has length more than 255 char open its **Column Conversion Details** Dialog then close it
then next to end...Lool