# Cannot import long text from Excel to SQL Server using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, etl, sql-server-2019

Environment:

- Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2112 Build 16.0.14729.20254) 64-bit
- Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU14) (KB5007182) - 15.0.4188.2 (X64)
- Microsoft Visual Studio 2019
- `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\REGISTRY\MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Access Connectivity Engine\Engines\Excel\TypeGuessRows` set to `0`

In Excel I formated the cell as "Text" and I also filled up the 2nd and 3rd rows with some super-long dummy text... (1st row is title row)

When I go to Excel Source/Advanced editor, I can set the Output to **Unicode text stream [DT_NTEXT]** or anything else but the External column cannot be changed to something else than **Unicode string [DT_WSTR] (255 characters)** despite the setting in registry that normally should allow it and despite having super-long strings in first two rows (other than the 1st row which holds the field names)

Then of course when I try to execute the SSIS task it throws a normal truncation error.

**Question:** What I am doing wrong or what else should be done here to actually be able to import the data? By the way, this is supposed to be automated at some point.

Comment: Try changing the columns length from the advanced editor. Check my answer update (section IV)

Answer (score 4):

Since an Excel workbook is not a database, the OLE DB provider tries to detect the most relevant metadata from the Excel worksheet and read it as tabular data, which is mostly inaccurate when handling medium and large Excel files. After spending years on creating SSIS packages, **I will convert the Excel file to a CSV file and import it using a Flat File Connection Manager instead**. Or I will use a C# script to import the data.

#### I. Converting Excel to CSV

You can automate the process of converting Excel to CSV using a C# script:

- [Converting XLSX file using to a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42926710/converting-xlsx-file-using-to-a-csv-file)
- [Convert .xlsx & .xls to .csv](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/246772/Convert-xlsx-xls-to-csv)
- [How to Convert Excel to CSV using Interop](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/683804/How-to-Convert-Excel-to-CSV-using-Interop)

After converting the Excel file to a CSV file, you can dynamically import it using a Flat File Connection Manager:

- [Dynamic Flat File Connections in SQL Server Integration Services](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1084/dynamic-flat-file-connections-in-sql-server-integration-services/)

#### II. Using a C# script

It is good to check the following class, which is a part of the SchemaMapper project:

- [SchemaMapper - MsExcelImport.cs](https://github.com/munchy-bytes/SchemaMapper/blob/master/SchemaMapperDLL/Classes/Converters/MsExcelImport.cs)

Besides, a step-by-step guide on how to use this library can be found in the following link:

- [Import data from multiple files into one SQL table step by step guide](https://github.com/munchy-bytes/SchemaMapper/wiki/Import-data-from-multiple-files-into-one-SQL-table-step-by-step-guide)

---

#### III. Editing the Excel connection string

If you don't have the choice to convert Excel to flat files, then you can force the Excel connection manager to ignore headers from the first row by adding `IMEX=1` to tell the OLEDB provider to specify data types from the first row *(which is the header - all string most of the time)*.

To edit the `connectionstring` property, click on the *Excel Connection Manager* and press on the <kbd>F4</kbd> key. In the *Properties Tab*, you can edit the `connectionstring` property.

- [SSIS Excel Import Columns with More or Less than 255 Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47899899/ssis-excel-import-columns-with-more-or-less-than-255-characters)

#### IV. Changing columns length from advanced editor

Try changing the Excel Source column metadata from the advanced editor:

- [In SSIS excel datasource not taking more characters than 255](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57644766/in-ssis-excel-datasource-not-taking-more-characters-than-255/57651599#57651599)

---

**Importing Excel using SSIS may cause a headache!** You can check the following question:

- [Workaround for exporting data to Excel with more than 255 columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42322816/workaround-for-exporting-data-to-excel-with-more-than-255-columns/42323906#42323906)
- [Dynamically Creating Excel table through SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56279923/dynamically-creating-excel-table-through-ssis/56283203#56283203)
- [SQL Server Import Wizard doesn't support importing from excel sheet with more than 255 columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56937693/sql-server-import-wizard-doesnt-support-importing-from-excel-sheet-with-more-th/56959932#56959932)
- [Importing Excel Data Seems to Randomly Give Null Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56369804/importing-excel-data-seems-to-randomly-give-null-values/56370426#56370426)
- [Failing to read String value from an excel column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56969446/failing-to-read-string-value-from-an-excel-column/56977847#56977847)
- [Importing Excel Data Seems to Randomly Give Null Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56369804/importing-excel-data-seems-to-randomly-give-null-values/56370426#56370426)
- [SSIS - Excel data shows as scientific notations and Null Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57419213/ssis-excel-data-shows-as-scientific-notations-and-null-values/57420869#57420869)

Comment: I agree c# is better than the SSIS tools, and would consider using ExcelDataReader Nuget and load to DataTable and then use a SqlBulkCopy to load the data. There are a few steps to do that, but it is extremely efficient.

Comment: @KeithL all needed code is in the SchemaMapper project mentioned in my answer